# Shopware 6 Administration: read listFilterOptions() in SwProductList from custom plugin component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopware6

Version Shopware 6.4.20

My custom plugin a component is imported by overridden [`SwProductDetail`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-product/page/sw-product-detail/index.js). The imported component need the [`SwProductList`.`filterOptions`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/99a447f97891e42ae357196bd261c854fb5912a2/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-product/page/sw-product-list/index.js#L127).

How can i read the list from `SwProductList` inside the component above?

Answer (score 0):

```
// myComponent.js

...
const fnFilterOptions = Shopware.Component.getComponentRegistry().get('sw-product-list').computed.listFilterOptions;
const filters = fnFilterOptions.call(this)
...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve your problem specifically but they don't help future readers understand the solution.